# How to denote null values and empty lists and dictionaries in Firebase's Realtime Database?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to denote the following as an actual value in Firebase's Realtime Database:

- Empty lists
- Empty dictionaries
- Null / none / nil

These values, when posted to the database along with the key, will not show up in the database. For example, this is what an example database would look like before the update request, in JSON format:

```json
{
    "foo": 0
}
```

This is the following update request, written in python:

```py
data = {
    "normal_list": [1, 2, 3],
    "empty_list": [],
    "normal_dict": {"bar": "bar2"},
    "empty_dict": {},
    "null": None,
    "normal_value": 69
}
database.set(data)
```

This is what the database would look like after the update request, in JSON format:

```json
{
    "foo": 0,
    "normal_list": [1, 2, 3],
    "normal_dict": {"bar": "bar2"},
    "normal_value": 69
}
```

As you can see, there is no entry for the null value and the empty list and dictionary.

My solution here was to try to set the problematic values as some special string, *then* send it to the database. For getting the data, just reset the string to the problematic value before being used.

```py
{
    "normal_list": [1, 2, 3],
    "empty_list": "--emptylist--",
    "normal_dict": {"bar": "bar2"},
    "empty_dict": "--emptydict--",
    "null": "--none--",
    "normal_value": 69
}
```

This raises some security issues though, what if the user using the program sent a string like `"--emptylist--"`? I'm not sure if a simple iterative `new_string = f"this_is_just_a_string({old_string})"` is good enough if the user did some really screwed up shenanigans that I didn't know.

**Is there a better way of fixing this problem? Or is my solution good enough?**

"Good enough" meaning:

- No possible way to trick either the database/program into using/storing unexpected values; and
- Easy to get / store data in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you shouldn't do this. Storing null values in a NoSQL database is not advised.

Your code should instead have logic to validate if a key is present and then respond accordingly to your needs. You're already adding logic to turn null values into fake-null values, so you're basically already doing this, twice. Once to turn null into fake-null, and once to turn fake-null into null.

I think the best option would be to pass anything you load through a function that returns what you want, so you don't have to store null values. This will save you the logic of turning null into fake-null, and you're not storing the fake-null in your database.

How easily this is implementable does depend on the complexity of your JSON though.

See the example below, and the `example` dict should be what you loaded from the Firebase RTDB

```py
from pprint import pprint


default_json = {
    "normal_list": [],
    "empty_list": [],
    "normal_dict": {},
    "empty_dict": {},
    "null": None,
    "normal_value": 0,
    "somestring": "default value",
}


def add_default_kv_pairs(data):
    for key, default_value in default_json.items():
        if key not in data:
            data[key] = default_value
    return data


example = {"normal_value": 12}
pprint(add_default_kv_pairs(example))
```

**output**

```py
{'empty_dict': {},
 'empty_list': [],
 'normal_dict': {},
 'normal_list': [],
 'normal_value': 12,
 'null': None,
 'somestring': 'default value'}
```